# Is it possible to change the current map document from a geoprocessing tool

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, mxd

I'm writing a `BaseGeoprocessingTool` with the ArcObjects API and I need to open an Mxd then change the current document by this opened document.

I managed to open the Mxd document:

```
IMapDocument mapDocument = new MapDocument();
mapDocument.open(filename, "");
```

And inside a geoprocessing tool, it's possible to get the current map or page layout by using `gpUtilities.getMap()` or `gpUtilities.getActiveView()`.

But is it possible to get the current `IApplication` in order to set the current document?

Or is there another way to change the current document?

Else, I need to handle the current document, in order to change data frame settings, Maplex settings, print and export settings... not only layers.

I use ArcMap 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

> But is it possible to get the current IApplication in order to set the
>   current document?

If you can't get a reference to the application object, may be you can instantiate a new AppRef object

```
IApplication baseApp = (IApplication)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriFramework.AppRef"));
```

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000nm000000

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I use the Java SDK. So, I tried to instanciate 'IApplication application = new com.esri.arcgis.framework.AppRef();' and I get a 'AutomationException: 0x8000ffff - Catastrophic failure'. I also tried 'IApplication application = new com.esri.arcgis.arcmap.Application();' then I get a 'AutomationException: 0x80040154 - Class not registered'. Maybe, there are other things to do before, maybe it's not possible to create these objects in Java side. Does it works in .NET?